# How to setup python3 version on mac?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pyenv

I have installed `python 3.8.0` via `pyenv`.

```
pyenv which python
/Users/myname/.pyenv/versions/3.8.0/bin/python
```

If I run `python3` I get

```
python3           
Python 3.6.8rc1 (v3.6.8rc1:cc3e73212a, Dec 11 2018, 17:37:34) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

If I check

```
which python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3
```

How can I set the `3.8.0` version as default?

Comment: @python_user I get `command not found: python3.8`

Comment: Pyenv environments need to be [activated](https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/#activating-your-versions) first

Answer (score 0):

By typing `pyenv global 3.8`

You check get the list of options by typing `pyenv -h`

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple versions of python installed, you can do `python -3.x -m ...`

Also check if the env is active before opening it.